# ComboBox loses Selected Value

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I have a combobox inside of my WPF DataGrid.  It is created like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Account">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Account, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Accounts}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Account, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="23" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The DataContext for this datagrid is an ObservableCollection.  The Transaction class has a Property called "Account"  Below is how I create this property:

```
public string Account
{
    get { return account; }
    set { account = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Account"); }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  When I choose an item from the ComboBox, nothing is displayed after I click outside of the box.  When I set a break point in the Set method of the Account Property, the value is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed my issue. I had to set the `Text` property binding.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Accounts}" Text="{Binding Path=Account}" Height="23" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `SelectedValue` in your `ComboBox` to `SelectedItem`. Have a read up on the differences between the two on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue.aspx).

Comment: This still isn't working after changing it to SelectedItem. The issue remains the same without any differences.  Should something be changed in the binding of the TextBlock instead?